# Google sheets not let me use time with this format hour:minute

Tags: time, google-sheets

I not understand why i can't use the format hour:minute in google sheet. I already try everything and i not understand how to do.

A1  05:30 formatted in format-->number-->other formats hour:minute

A2  =HOUR(A1)

nothing he not work because he think a1 is text. if i do with the default format 05.30 everything works.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p2NbIVN52sAPNb5FmAWytDimU9QHAnZzWUrWU2xImfw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to provide more details about your issue. I typed `05:30` in a cell, then **Format** -> **Number** -> **More Formats** -> **More date and time formats**. Click on **Hour** -> **Hour with leading zero**. And it shows as desired: `05:30`

Comment: i added a example

Comment: "he think a1 is text." - True, insert this anywhere (`=istext(A1)`) and you'll find that it IS text.

Comment: @user215023 Have you solved this problem now?